# Difference between дальний and далёкий!

Tags: прилагательные

I find it very difficult to understand the difference in meaning and usage between дальний и далёкий!

My teacher said:
дальний: is "far" in relation to my (or the speaker's) position
далёкий: is "far" in general.

But I feel like it's the opposite! Am I wrong? If I say "они живут в дальних селах" I feel like this "far" is a general, absolute far. It's far from everything else.

Can someone give me a better explanation of the difference? 
Thank you :)

Answer (score 5):

Your teacher is right. Talking about distances, "**дальний**" is close to "a further one", while "**далёкий**" is more like "a far one".

**Example 1:**
1st town ---------------- 2nd town -------------3rd town

There are three towns on the same interstate. We live in the first one. A man lives in the 3rd town. We say: "*Он живёт в **дальнем** городе*". A woman lives in the 2nd town - "*Она живёт в **ближнем** городе*".

**Example 2:**
1st town <---------------- 1000 miles -------------> 2rd town

We are in the 1st town, some person is in the 2nd town 1000 miles away. We would say "*Человек живёт в **далёком** городе*"

The word "**дальний**" implies the existence of closer objects (*ближний*).

Answer (score 2):

In some contexts *there is no real difference*.  Both are formed from the word "*даль*".  They are often interchangeable, and we can find idiomatic phrases with both words as attributes: "*дальний* путь", "*далёкий* путь" (see [here](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C%2C%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=25&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2C%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3B%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B%D0%94%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2C%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3B%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B%D0%94%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C%3B%2Cc0) for relative use statistics).

Stable antonyms to those are, respectively, "*ближний*" и "*близкий*", which are also rather very similar, although there are some phrases that would use the second word but not the first (you'd say "*близкий человек*", but "*ближнее зарубежье*" -- former Soviet republics after USSR had broken up).

Yet, as Roman points out, and where your teacher is correct, *when you need to use comparative sense*, "*дальний*" would be better (meaning "farth**er**"), same with the antonyms: "*ближний*" also has a meaning of "clos**er**", "near**er**".

---

The meaning really depends on the context, and so does their use.  For instance, with the noun "*дорога*", the phrase "*дальняя дорога*" means "*road to far away places*", i.e. "*road that [starts here and] leads far away*", whereas "*далёкая дорога*" has more of the meaning "*the road far away*", "*the road such that to reach it you need to travel far*".

Comment: thanks for the explanation and the examples! Seeing дальний as a comparative makes more sense

Answer (score 2):

> они живут в дальних сёлах = they are living in villages which are
>   difficult to reach, in the outskirts of the populated area (whether you are there or not), far from the central area
>
> они живут в далёких сёлах = they are living in the far villages, from you, from another place or from each other. They may be not far from the area's center.

Comment: they are leaving - they are living